# Add event to iCal

Tags: objective-c, events, calendar, icloud, icalendar

I am having issues with the CalCalendar framework.
I want to retrieve a default iCloud calendar and add events to it.
This is my code but I have this "error: The Reminds calendar does not support events".

```
IBOutlet NSDatePicker *minDatePicker;

/////

#import <CalendarStore/CalendarStore.h>


-(void)awakeFromNib {

[minDatePicker setDateValue:[NSDate date]];  
[minDatePicker setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

}


-(IBAction)addEvent:(id)sender {

CalCalendarStore *calendarStore = [CalCalendarStore defaultCalendarStore];
NSArray *calendars = [calendarStore calendars];

for (CalCalendar *calendar in calendars) {
    if (calendar) {

        CalEvent *event = [CalEvent event];

[event setTitle:@"title"];
[event setStartDate:[minDatePicker dateValue]];
[event setEndDate:[minDatePicker dateValue]];
[event setCalendar:calendar];

    NSError *error;
    [calendarStore saveEvent:event span:CalSpanThisEvent error:&error];

        NSLog(@"error:%@", [error localizedDescription]);


     break;   
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am not supposed to put anything here that does not answer the question. But, strangely, I noticed the same error on exactly the same day. Would it be possible that something changed in the framework? Or are we just doing the same thing wrong, at the same time? Hopefully someone will shine a light on this. If I figure it out, I will be sure to post it here!

Your code looks fine to me, btw!

Comment: I think there's our mistake, but maybe there is something wrong. I found this, so I will wait the new framework.
http://gazapps.com/wp/2012/02/19/os-x-v10-8-mountain-lion-new-frameworks/

Comment: That sounds plausible, but I am still not sure why this would affect us under snow leopard!